# How can I change the UIScrollView behaviour to start scrolling at > 0?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I've been struggling with a logic issue related to UIScrollViews for a few days now. My goal is to render a temperature slider that starts at a variable minimum temperature and stops at a maximum temperature.

For this I draw every ten points a line, which should represent a degree. I want the slider to start at 0 degrees Celsius or 273 Kelvin and be positioned in the middle of the screen. So I calculate **273*10** and get the desired starting point of the UIScrollview. In addition, I subtract half of the points on the screen and then scroll there. It works without any problems when the specified minimum temperature is <= 0.

This is the result when the temperature starts at <= 0 and is rendered:

[image: slider beginning under zero]

If I do the whole thing with Kelvin or the Celsius temperature starts at >0, the Scrollview does not stop scrolling until at about -187 K, which of course should not happen:

[image]

This is the formula I use right now:

```
// CONTENT SIZE
self.universalRulerScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: (maxTemp*10) + halfScreenWidth, height: scrollHeight)

// LEFT INSET
self.universalRulerScroll.contentInset.left = CGFloat(abs(minTemp)*10) + CGFloat(halfScreenWidth)

// SCROLL AT THE BEGINNING TO:
self.universalRulerScroll.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: -CGFloat(halfScreenWidth)+(zeroTemp*10), y: 0)
```

Maybe someone sees the logic error right off the bat? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some more information?  What are `maxTemp`, `minTemp` and `zeroTemp` in each case?

Comment: Sure, for Kelvin: minTemp = 187.125, maxTemp = 374.25 and zeroTemp = 273.15
– for Celsius: minTemp =  -86.02, maxTemp = 101.1 and zeroTemp =  0.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't really follow your math.  Assuming each degree mark is 10 points wide (which is why you are multiplying by 10) You probably want something like:

```
let tempRange = maxTemp - minTemp  // Width is number of degrees * 10 points

let zeroPosition = zeroTemp - minPosition // Zero position is offset by leftmost (minimum) degrees

self.universalRulerScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: tempRange * 10, height: scrollHeight)

self.universalRulerScroll.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: zeroPosition * 10 + halfScreenWidth, y: 0)
```